# What kind of route would I need to provide vanity urls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, vanity-url

I'd like to provide my users a vanity url, something like:

```
www.foo.com/sergio
```

What kind of route would I need to create?

Imagine I have the following controller and action, how can I map a vanity URL to that controller?

```
public ActionResult Profile(string username)
{
    var model = LoadProfile(username);
    return View(model);
}
```

---

Here is what I've tried and what happens:

### Option A:

Every url is caught in this route, meaning every URL I type directs me towards the Account controller, instead of only `foo.com/[USERNAME]`. No good.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Profile",
        "{username}",
        new { controller = "Account", action = "Profile", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

---

### Option B:

Default routes work well, but when trying to visit a profile `foo.com/[USERNAME]` I get an HTTP 404 error.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "DentistProfile",
        "{username}",
        new { controller = "Account", action = "Profile", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution could be using custom route constraint as,

```
public class VanityUrlContraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private static readonly string[] Controllers =
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(x))
            .Select(x => x.Name.ToLower().Replace("controller", "")).ToArray();

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values,
                      RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return !Controllers.Contains(values[parameterName].ToString().ToLower());
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Profile",
        url: "{username}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Account", action = "Profile"},
        constraints: new { username = new VanityUrlContraint() }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

downside of this approach, profile view for usernames same as existing controller name will not work, like if there are usernames like "asset", "location", and "AssetController", "LocationController" exists in project, profile view for "asset", "location" will not work.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you this worked extremely well! I'll just have to create a `List<string>` of not allowed vanity URL's just to be safe. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"YourRouteName",
"{username}",
new {controller="YourController", action="Profile", username=UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

This should trap www.foo.com/{username}. Remember that routes are checked in the order you add them, so you can add

```
routes.MapRoute(
"default",
"{controller}/{action}/{input}",
new {controller="controller", action="action", input=UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

first to maintain the "default" behavior.

Comment: This doesn't work as intended, please see edit. :) I've placed a bounty on the question as well.