# route to capture item after first forward slash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having a challenging time trying to create a working route that will let me capture the first item after the forward slash (and ideally nothing after that).

For example, www.mywebsite.com/item1, www.mywebsite.com/item2, www.mywebsite.com/item2

The item will only ever be letters or numbers with no spaces or other characters.

Any ideas?

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("UsernameRoute", "{Username}", new { controller = "Home", action = "GetUsername" }, new { Username = new UsernameConstraint() });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );            
    }
```

and in the home controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetUsername(string username)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = username;

        return View("Username");
    }
```

and the route constraint file:

```
public class UsernameConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return true; //set to true for now to test but will lookup username in database here
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you got so far? We can help you fix it.

Comment: I've added some code. It kinda works, I mean it detects the route but I don't like having it in the Home controller (would rather have it in the Account controller, and it also isn't passing the username through)

Comment: answered a similar question a while back, it has some downside though, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558541/what-kind-of-route-would-i-need-to-provide-vanity-urls