# ASP.NET MVC Routing - Thousands of URL's

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

My ecommerce application stores URL's for item pages in the database.  There are thousands of these URL's, which are all root level (i.e. domain-name.com/{item-page-url}).

If I add all of these URL's to the route table by using a simple for loop to call RouteCollection.MapRoute for each URL site performance degrades exponentially. Why? The reason for this is [here](http://www.devbridge.com/articles/refactoring-asp-net-mvc3-routes/).

How should I properly handle this situation?  Adding all of the routes to the route table doesn't seem right (not to mention the performance pretty much confirms that).  I've seen a few ideas about inspecting all incoming URL's and then trying to match that to the URL's in the database but don't fully understand how I'd implement that, nor am I sure if it's the best approach.

Any ideas or suggestions?  This seems like it would be not so uncommon, but I haven't found a concrete way to handle it.

Comment: What does each `{item-page-url}` look like?  Can you provide a couple of examples?

Comment: Sure....  www.mydomain.com/car-wash-tri-fold-brochure-template.aspx or www.mydomain.com/child-care-pediatrician-office-brochure-template.aspx

Comment: answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558541/what-kind-of-route-would-i-need-to-provide-vanity-urls/13641225. it might help you.

Comment: That's it.  Route constraints solve it..just didn't understand how to do it until I saw your post.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your route to 
**mycreativeshop.com/product/my-product-name** then adding following route to the top of your route config file can help you.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "CustomRouteProduct",
                "product/{id}",
                new { controller = "yourcontrollername", action = "Index" }
            );
```

and in the action map the parameter value with name of your product name

```
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
            {
             //var prdName = id.Replace("-", " ");
            //look up prdName in database                
            return View();
            }
```

**Update** 
Added following as a top route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "CustomRouteProductZX",
                "{id}",
                new { controller = "Content", action = "Index" }
            );
```

and by accessing `http://localhost:12025/Car-Paint` I was directed to Index action of ContentController where I accessed "**Car-Paint**" in parameter **id**

But, above having above blocks patterns like `http://localhost:12025/Home/` (here Home is also treated as a product)

Comment: Yeah, I'm very familiar with how to do that.  The issue is I'm need to handle root-level URL's that hang directly off the domain.